# Wagtail : How do I query related names (inline models) of a child page?

Tags: python, django, django-models, wagtail

I have two pages:

ArticlePage and TimelinePage.

TimelinePage has an inline panel which is related to the model TimelinePageEntry.

TimelinePage displays all of it's child TimelinePageEntry(s) just fine. However when I try to get all the TimelinePageEntry(s) from ArticlePage, it fails with an exception.

ArticlePage fails with an exception when I try to do:

```
context['timeline_entries'] = timeline_page.timeline_entries.all()
```

Here's the source code for the three classes in models.py:

```
import datetime

from django.db import models
from modelcluster.fields import ParentalKey
from wagtail.admin.edit_handlers import FieldPanel, InlinePanel
from wagtail.core.fields import RichTextField
from wagtail.core.models import Orderable
from wagtail.core.models import Page


class ArticlePage(Page):
    date = models.DateField("Creation date", default=datetime.date.today)
    hero_biography = RichTextField(blank=True)

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel('date'),
        FieldPanel('hero_biography'),
    ]

    subpage_types = [
        'articles.TimelinePage'
    ]

    def get_context(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context(request)
        timeline_pages = self.get_children().type(TimelinePage)
        timeline_page = timeline_pages[0]

        # prints "Page"
        print(type(timeline_page).__name__)
        
        # prints the title of the timeline page, so I know I'm getting a query result
        print(timeline_page.title)

        context['timeline_page'] = timeline_page

        # Throws an exception
        context['timeline_entries'] = timeline_page.timeline_entries.all()

        return context


class TimelinePage(Page):
    max_count_per_parent = 1
    subpage_types = []

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        InlinePanel('timeline_entries', label="Timeline Entries")
    ]

    parent_page_type = [
        'articles.ArticlePage'
    ]

    def get_context(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # Prints "TimelinePage"
        print(type(self).__name__)

        # Prints a list of timeline entries
        print(repr(self.timeline_entries.all()))

        return super().get_context(request)


class TimelinePageEntry(Orderable):
    page = ParentalKey(TimelinePage, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='timeline_entries')

    start_date = models.DateField()
    end_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)

    line = RichTextField(max_length=90)

    panels = [
        FieldPanel('start_date'),
        FieldPanel('end_date'),
        FieldPanel('line'),
    ]

    class Meta(Orderable.Meta):
        ordering = ['-start_date']
```

It seems like what I am trying to do should be really simple. TimelinePage is a child of
ArticlePage. I am able to access other attributes of TimelinePage (the title) from ArticlePage, but I'm stumped on how to get the TimelinePageEntries.

The exception that I get is:

```
    context['timeline_entries'] = timeline_page.timeline_entries.all()
AttributeError: 'Page' object has no attribute 'timeline_entries'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to the distinction between `Page` instances (which just contain the data common to all page types, such as title) and instances of your specific `TimelinePage` subclass (which provides access to all the methods, fields and relations defined on that class).

`self.get_children()` returns a queryset of type `Page`; this is necessary because the query doesn't know in advance what page types will be included in the results. `.type(TimelinePage)` filters this to just pages of the given type, but this only acts as a filter on the existing queryset - the results will still remain as `Page` objects, which are missing the `timeline_entries` relation.

If you rewrite the line

```
timeline_pages = self.get_children().type(TimelinePage)
```

into

```
timeline_pages = TimelinePage.objects.child_of(self)
```

then this will ensure that the results are returned as TimelinePage instances, and the `timeline_entries` relation will then work as intended.

Comment: Thank you, this solution worked perfectly. I thought that type casting was not supposed to be a thing in Python, so I was thrown by this type of solution.